# Repeated select statement for retention analysis

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working on retention analysis for a subscription product using a temporary table that logs all customer entitlements. Each line in the table has:

```
customer_id, produc_id, start_date, expiration_date, product_serial_number, ...
```

Customer_id is unique. If a customer renews the product at expiration date, new expiration date will be updated to the table daily.

Usually at the monthly analysis, I count customer_id, then group by YYYY-MM (extracted from start_date) as the base of the cohort. Then I put in a sum & case statement such as:

```
sum(case when expiration_date >= ADD_MONTHS(start_date,1) then 1 else 0 end) as 'T+1M'
sum(case when expiration_date >= ADD_MONTHS(start_date,2) then 1 else 0 end) as 'T+2M'
....
```

I hardcode every "sum + case when" line for each period I want to check for retention. It works well for monthly. But now I want to look closer at daily level for a customer behavior for 60 days before expiration date. I wonder if there is anyway more efficient than writing 60 lines such as:

```
sum(case when opt_out_date >= expiration_date-1) then 1 else 0 end) as 'OO_T-1'
sum(case when opt_out_date >= expiration_date-2) then 1 else 0 end) as 'OO_T-2'
....
```

sum(case when opt_out_date >= expiration_date-60) then 1 else 0 end) as 'OO_T-60'

opt_out_date is the date that a user decides to cancel the auto-billing feature.This analysis is to check right before expiration date, how many users manually cancel their auto-billing.

The environment is Teradata

Thanks alot.

Sample data and expected result added as recommended
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suha7.png)

[Expected result from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DltM.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.

Comment: Sample data should text tables in question, not images.

Comment: If you need 60 columns you have to write code for 60 columns, it's mainly cut&paste&modify. You might create those 60 CASEs using SQL or Excel, butfinally it's the same code.